# jquery/pdfobject problem to embed pdf to a div

Tags: jquery

I have this working code:

```
$.post("./php/acc_con_def.php",
    {contratto:contratto,vers:vers,scelta:"nuovo"}, 
    function(data){
        window.open("./temp/accettazione.pdf")
});
```

I'm tring to use this code to open pdf in a div but it doesnt work here is my used code:

```
    $.post("./php/acc_con_def.php",
    {contratto:contratto,vers:vers,scelta:"nuovo"}, 
    function(data){
        $("#hideShow").show("slow");
        function embedPDF(){
            var myPDF = new PDFObject({ 
              url: './temp/accettazione.pdf'
            }).embed('hideShow'); 
          }
          window.onload = embedPDF; 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$.post("./php/acc_con_def.php", {contratto:contratto,vers:vers,scelta:"nuovo"}, 
  function(data) {

    $("#hideShow").show("slow");
    var myPDF = new PDFObject({ url: './temp/accettazione.pdf' }).embed('hideShow'); 

  }
);
```

if you want to do when you finish loading the page, you must do so:

```
$(function() {

    $.post("./php/acc_con_def.php", {contratto:contratto,vers:vers,scelta:"nuovo"}, 
      function(data) {

        $("#hideShow").show("slow");
        var myPDF = new PDFObject({ url: './temp/accettazione.pdf' }).embed('hideShow'); 

      }
    );

});
```

the problem in your code is that after making the post, the event "load" of "window" ended.

**EDIT**

try this code to see if your browser is working well:

```
    $("#hideShow").show();
    $.post("./php/acc_con_def.php", {contratto:contratto,vers:vers,scelta:"nuovo"}, 
      function(data) {

         if ($.browser.msie)
            $("#hideShow").append('<div><object width="100%" height="100%" classid="CLSID:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000" data="./temp/accettazione.pdf#" type="application/pdf"/></div>');
         else
            $("#hideShow").append('<div><object type="application/pdf" data="./temp/accettazione.pdf#" width="100%" height="100%"></object></div>');
      }
    );
```

**HTML for Test**
first create the file '`./temp/accettazione.pdf`'

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div>for IE</div>
  <div><object width="100%" height="100%" classid="CLSID:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000" data="./temp/accettazione.pdf#" type="application/pdf"/></div>
  <br /><br />
  <div>for other</div>
  <div><object type="application/pdf" data="./temp/accettazione.pdf#" width="100%" height="100%"></object></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @andres descalzo: thanks for answering, it doesnt work, my code is inside a fuction may be this the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JGUex/3/ This example works fine in Safari and Opera, I guess in other browsers is an issue of change domain.

Comment: can you see well this example 'http://pdfobject.com/examples/simplest.html'?, if you look good, create a html with the code that is in the response.

Comment: Hi Andres thanks for help I've tried your Html for test under IE and works, under firefox no I suppose it's a browser problem...at this point..